# c++ function to find the sum of four minimum maximum elements in an array not working

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11

I am solving a question in which i have to write a function which finds the maximum and minimum sum of any four integers in an array passed to it and then displays it.

here is my code:

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {

        int minsum=0;
        int maxsum=0;
        int l1,l2,l3,l4;
        int s1,s2,s3,s4;
        l1=arr[0];
        s1=arr[0];
        for(int i=1;i<arr.size();++i)
        {
            if(l1<arr[i])
            l1=arr[i];
            if(s1>arr[i])
            s1=arr[i];
        }
        l2=arr[0];
        s2=arr[0];
        for(int i=1;i<arr.size();++i)
        {
            if(l2<arr[i]&&arr[i]!=l1)
            l2=arr[i];
            if(s2>arr[i]&&arr[i]!=s1)
            s2=arr[i];
        }
        l3=arr[0];
        s3=arr[0];
        for(int i=1;i<arr.size();++i)
        {
            if(l3<arr[i]&&arr[i]!=l2&&arr[i]!=l1)
            l3=arr[i];
            if(s3>arr[i]&&arr[i]!=s2&&arr[i]!=s1)
            s3=arr[i];
        }
        l4=arr[0];
        s4=arr[0];
        for(int i=1;i<arr.size();++i)
        {
            if(l4<arr[i]&&arr[i]!=l2&&arr[i]!=l1&&arr[i]!=l3)
            l4=arr[i];
            if(s4>arr[i]&&arr[i]!=s3&&arr[i]!=s2&&arr[i]!=s1)
            s4=arr[i];
        }
        minsum=s1+s2+s3+s4;
        maxsum=l1+l2+l3+l4;
        cout<<minsum<<" "<<maxsum;
}
```

this code gives the correct output for maxsum but the minsum is wrong in all the testcases.
please help me find the error in the code
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This algorithm is going to fail if there are repeated elements in the minimum, or maximum 4. Have you considered sorting the array, and just looking at the first, and last 4?

Comment: @cigien it is also failing for arrays with no repetions.

Comment: for input 1,2,3,4,5     the result should be 10  14  but it is giving 4  14, why is that @cigien pls tell

Comment: Ok, why don't you provide a test case that fails, and show the expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @cigien yes bro for  the input 1,2,3,4,5 the output should be 10 14  but my output is 4 14

Comment: Because you initialize `s`s to `arr[0]`, which is the smallest element, and only update when you find a bigger element, which is impossible. So all your `s`s are 1.

Comment: and for  input 7 69 2 221 8974 the output is 23 9271 while it should be 299 9271

Comment: @cigien can you suggest another method for doing that?

Comment: Like I said above, sort the array, and look at the first, and last 4 elements. You can use `std::sort` for this. You can take a look at `std::nth_element` to be more efficient.

Comment: @cigien oh thanks, thats a nice idea, i will surely try it ...  thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214995/discussion-between-dhruv-bansal-and-cigien).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    int sumMin = 0, sumMax = 0, len = arr.size() - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        sumMin += arr[i];
        sumMax += arr[len - i];
    }
    cout<<"minimum sum: "<<sumMin<<endl;
    cout<<"maximum sum: "<<sumMax<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you considering complexity then as Daniel mentioned you can do that using `O(N log N)` but you can do that using `O(N)` where `N` is the length of the array.

Here is the code segment

```
void minMaxSum(vector<int> arr){
 int l1, l2, l3, l4; // large element;
 int s1, s2, s3, s4; // smallest element

 l1 = l2 = l3 = l4 = INT_MIN;
 s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = INT_MAX;

for(auto i:arr){
    if(i>=l1){
          l4 = l3;
          l3 = l2;
          l2 = l1;
          l1 = i;}
    else if(i>=l2){
          l4 = l3;
          l3 = l2;
          l2 = i;}
    else if(i>=l3){
          l4 = l3;
          l3 = i;}
    else if(i>=l4)
          l4 = i;
}
for(auto i:arr){
    if(i<=s1){
      s4 = s3;
      s3 = s2;
      s2 = s1;
          s1 = i;}
    else if(i<=s2){
          s4 = s3;
          s3 = s2;
          s2 = i;}
    else if(i<=s3){
          s4 = s3;
          s3 = i;}
    else if(i<=s4)
          s4 = i;
}
int minsum = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
int maxsum = l1 + l2 + l3 + l4;
cout << maxsum << " " << minsum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use the standard library:

```cpp
void miniMaxSum(const std::vector<int> & arr) {
  std::array<int, 4> small_numbers;
  std::partial_sort_copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
                         small_numbers.begin(), small_numbers.end(),
                         std::less<int>());

  std::array<int, 4> large_numbers;
  std::partial_sort_copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
                         large_numbers.begin(), large_numbers.end(),
                         std::greater<int>());

  std::cout << std::accumulate(small_numbers.begin(), small_numbers.end(), 0)
            << " "
            << std::accumulate(large_numbers.begin(), large_numbers.end(), 0)
            << std::endl;
}
```

Shown to work on https://repl.it/repls/EntireTornBotany

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array using C++ Stl sort(array,array+n) and then pick n number from starting or from ending . Would be completed in Big oh of nlogn